# SELinux: how to grant read access?

Tags: systemd, selinux

I have this `systemd` service with the following `PIDFile` property :

```
PIDFile=/home/john/.pm2/pm2.pid
```

You might have expected the file to be located under the `/run` directory. Unfortunately, that's the way it is and I can't change it directly ([I'm trying, though](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4813)).

Because of this, I get this error when I start the service

```
SELinux is preventing systemd from read access on the file pm2.pid.
```

Here is (what I think is) the relevant information :

```
Source Context                system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
```

I'd like to update the target context with `chcon` . I reckon I should update the third bit (aka the type), but I have no clue what to set.

How can I change the PID file's security context to make the error go away ?

Comment: A better way to do it would be to have the `PIDFile` in `/var/run` instead of your home directory where you have to give 755 permissions.

Comment: I fear I have no control on where the `PIDFile` is created. And I think the permission issue goes beyond `chmod`, as described.

Comment: You most certainly do have control over where it's created. You just need to read up on how to edit service and config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a rule does the trick. After trying to start the service (which results in a timeout), I had to run these commands as root

```
ausearch -c 'systemd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-systemd
semodule -i my-systemd.pp
```

All seems good now. Upon restart, the service is properly started.

Note that this solution might work only temporarily, as the new rules appears to be defined in a `/tmp/my-systemd.te` file. Here is its content (containing the actual policies of interest, I guess)

```
module my-systemd 1.0;

require {
        type init_t;
        type user_home_t;
        class file { open read };
}

#============= init_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow init_t user_home_t:file read;
allow init_t user_home_t:file open;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another options that doesn't require new SELinux rules:

Edit the `systemd` file that starts `pm2` and specify an alternative location for the `pm2` PIDFile). You'll have to make two changes, one to tell `pm2` where to place the PIDFile, and one to tell `systemd` where to look for it. Replace the existing PIDFile line with the following two lines

```
Environment=PM2_PID_FILE_PATH=/run/pm2.pid
PIDFile=/run/pm2.pid
```

If you have the permissions to add a new SELinux rule, you should have the permissions to edit the `systemd` file too.

Comment: This method worked.

Answer (score 2):

For reasons I haven't figured out yet, SELinux is blocking `pm2` but not logging it properly (even with changing configurations to show all logs), so there was nothing for me to pipe to `audit2allow`.

After spending half a day on it, my solution was to finally just create a custom .sh which runs `pm2` as my desired user, and then create a service to run that .sh.

> The following was done as root user.

1. Create directory `mkdir /usr/bin/pm2-startup`
2. Create script file `nano pm2-startup.sh` with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   runuser -l [insert desired username here] -c 'pm2 resurrect'
   ```
3. Create service file `nano /etc/systemd/system/pm2.service` with the following content:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Resurrect PM2 as [desired username]
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/pm2-startup/pm2_startup.sh
   TimeoutStartSec=0

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```
4. Reload systemd with `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Enable the newly created service with `systemctl enable pm2.service`
6. Start the service with `systemctl start pm2`
7. Ensure the service started with `systemctl status pm2`, then reboot to ensure pm2 is resurrected with `systemctl reboot`
8. After reboot, run `pm2 list` as whichever user you're using and confirm the apps are running.

If you check the status of this service after boot, it'll say `inactive` because it's literally just a service to run a single script and then it's done.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only one solution that helped me with `pm2` and `centos 8`.
2) Correct please file name `pm2-startup.sh` to `pm2_startup.sh`. Because `ExecStart=/usr/bin/pm2-startup/pm2_startup.sh` with underscore.
2.5) Enable to run `chmod +x pm2_startup.sh`