# Adding an SELinux rule to grant a user read/write access to specific file

Tags: permissions, selinux

I'm currently running into a problem where a user on my machine called `qemu` can't access certain files. For example `/dev/shm/looking-glass`.

I already ran:

```
sudo setfacl --modify user:$(logname):rw "/dev/shm/looking-glass"
sudo setfacl --modify user:qemu:rw "/dev/shm/looking-glass"
```

Here's some more info on the permissions on that file:

```
$ ls -la /dev/shm/looking-glass 
-rw-rw----+ 1 qemu kvm 33554432 Jul 29 01:29 /dev/shm/looking-glass

$ getfacl /dev/shm/looking-glass 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/shm/looking-glass
# owner: qemu
# group: kvm
user::rw-
user:qemu:rw-
user:fedora:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

The file permissions and ownership for this particular file are managed through `systemd-tmpfiles` btw:

```
$ cat /etc/tmpfiles.d/10-looking-glass.conf
#Type Path               Mode UID  GID Age Argument
f /dev/shm/looking-glass 0660 qemu kvm -
```

I also tried using `setfacl` directly on `/dev` and `/dev/shm`, but that completely messed up my system and it didn't help anyway, so I had to undo it.

Now if I simply set SELinux to permissive (`sudo setenforce 0`)

The `qemu` user can access that file without any issues.

But I want to keep SELinux set to enforcing, so that is not an option.

Now my question is: How can I add a rule to SELinux that grants a given user access to a given file?

The only related question I was able to find is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604679/selinux-how-to-grant-read-access) which is only about adding rules for a systemd service, so that doesn't help in my case.